# SQL Server, Advanced Scaping quotes

Tags: sql, escaping, quotes

I'm having some trouble trying to create a procedure which uses dynamic querys and parameters.
I'm using `sp_msforeachdb` and it receives a parameter as a string, this string is dynamic and contents some other strings...

To clarify, this is my example:

```
SET @vTableName = '##temp_table_' + convert(NVARCHAR(8), getdate(),112)

SET @vQuery = ' sp_msforeachdb 
    ''use ? IF db_name() LIKE (''%_BASE'')

    INSERT INTO ''+@vTableName+'' 
         SELECT *
           FROM elements 
                WHERE identifier = ''P''
''
'
```

Could anybody help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you would like to do with the use statement, but have amended a few quotes.

```
DECLARE @vTableName varchar(2000)
DECLARE @vQuery varchar(2000)
SET @vTableName = '##temp_table_' + convert(NVARCHAR(8), getdate(),112)

SET @vQuery = ' sp_msforeachdb 
    ''use ? IF db_name() LIKE (''%_BASE'')

    INSERT INTO '+@vTableName+' 
         SELECT *
           FROM elements 
                WHERE identifier = ''P''
'
```